# Is it possible to use a glass material in a "Designed for iPad" app on Apple Vision Pro?

Tags: ios, xcode, visionos

It's unclear how to use this example given by Apple.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override var preferredContainerBackgroundStyle: UIContainerBackgroundStyle {
        return .glass
    }
}
```

If I try overriding the property, I get an error saying it only builds on visionOS. However, adding a compiler directive check for visionOS only returns true if the app is fully native for visionOS (no storyboards). Does this mean that UIKit enhancements are only supported for UIKit embedded in the fully native target?

[image]

Comment: Probably not since "Designed for iPad" is just an iPadOS app the this variable is only available for VisionOS

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The docs say this is only for visionOS:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/4245793-preferredcontainerbackgroundstyl

Keep in mind, when you used "Designed for", it is basically UIKit that is running inside Vision OS.